# new to coding and python. trying to force type (int) for a float answer

Tags: python

```
balance = 50 - 0.12 * 15
tracks_left = balance / 0.12
round (tracks_left, 0)
print 'you have', tracks_left,"to download"
```

The answer is `you have 401.666666667 to download`
I've tried `round(tracks_left, 0)` and `int (tracks_left)`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`round(tracks_left, 0)` does not mutate tracks_left, but instead returns a new value. Likewise with `int(tracks_left)`.

Try:

```
tracks_left = round(tracks_left, 0)
```

Or:

```
tracks_left = int(tracks_left)
```

Note: `int` always rounds down.

Answer (score 1):

`round(tracks_left, 0)` doesn't change `tracks_left`. It just returns the value. You have to assign it to something.

```
>>> balance = 50 - 0.12 * 15
>>> tracks_left = balance / 0.12
>>> tracks_left_rounded = round(tracks_left, 0)
>>> print('You have', tracks_left_rounded)
You have 402.0
```

You could as well  do this:

```
>>> balance = 50 - 0.12 * 15
>>> tracks_left = round(balance / 0.12)
```

You can also try `int`:

```
>>> tracks_left_rounded = int(tracks_left)
>>> print('You have', tracks_left_rounded)
You have 401
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: That was awesome!  Worked beautifully and I just understood something else. I have to assign the new value to a variable before I can reference it which is what Ive been doing wrong.  Thanks a lot.